# Как исправить ошибку Git в Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio

Пишет вот такую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понял, что не правильно указан путь или директория... Но когда я перехожу в настройки то там все правильно вроде.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что я делаю не так?

Comment: Хранить репозиторий в дропбоксе -- так себе идея. Это так, к сведению.

Comment: Почему? Это ж локальный... Мало ли что с ноутом произойдет, так локальная копия останется в дропе...

Comment: Так а гитхаб с ветками вам зачем? .-.

Comment: Я новичок, гитом не давно научился пользоваться. Нужно будет разобраться с ветками

Comment: Заметно. Урок первый: ваш вопрос про гит, а не про гитхаб :) Поправьте вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: Git это репозитории в целом, верно? А GitHub это конкретный, так?

Comment: Git это система контроля версий. а GitHub это хостинг для её репозиториев.

Comment: И проблема явно не в git, а в Android Studio. Разберитесь с директориями у себя на диске. По простому - директория, в которой есть папка .git и является `Git root`

Comment: Не используйте Dropbox для резервного копирования репозиториев Git. Для этого Git и является распределенной системой контроля версий — репозиторий можно и нужно бэкапить в другом репозитории. Используйте любой хостинг репозиториев, например GitHub или Bitbucket.

Comment: А у вас там вообще репозиторий Git есть? Попробуйте выполнить команду `ls -ld .git` в папке проекта.

Answer (score 1):

Не используйте Dropbox для резервного копирования репозиториев Git. Для этого Git и является распределенной системой контроля версий — репозиторий можно и нужно бэкапить в другом репозитории. Используйте любой хостинг репозиториев, например GitHub или Bitbucket.

Предлагаю радикальный способ исправить ошибку — сделать всё заново и правильно.

Шаги такие:

1. Перенесите файлы своего проекта в папку, не лежащую внутри Dropbox.
2. Не вполне понятно, есть у вас там сейчас репозиторий или нет. Так что в корневой папке своего проекта [(пере)инициализируйте Git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428154/181472):

   ```
   cd /home/aleksey/projects/learnhebrew/
   rm -r .git
   git init
   ```
3. Поскольку у вас IDE, есть много файлов не подлежащих контролю версий. [Добавьте `.gitignore`.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474556/181472)
4. Зарегистрируйтесь на любом хостинге. (Github более популярен для опенсорса, Bitbucket позволяет бесплатные непубличные репозитории).
5. Создайте там проект и следуйте инструкциям по подключению его к локальному.

Теперь стандартный рабочий процесс у вас такой:

1. Добавляете файлы в индекс — это подготовка очередного коммита.

   ```
   git add somedir someotherdir and/a/file.txt
   git add .

   # передумали? можно убрать файл из индекса
   git reset filename.txt path
   ```
2. Делаете из индекса коммит (хранит снимок рабочей папки проекта в определенный момент):

   ```
   git commit -m 'message to explain changes'
   ```
3. Отправляете на удалённый репозиторий с помощью `push`:

   ```
   # в первый раз
   git push -u origin master

   # потом
   git push
   ```

Comment: Я перенес папку со своим проектом в другую дерикторию(не дропбокс), потом защел в вновь созданую дерикторию куда перенес свой проект и  выполнил команду как написано в п.2 и вот что показывает консоль " rm: cannot remove ‘.git/objects/a1’: Directory not empty
rm: remove write-protected regular file ‘.git/objects/60/542fb7c5b9b1fafcaa57314125094690f50038’?" когда я нажимаю enter опять то же самое показывает... ЧТо я делаю не так?