# Случайно выполнил git init и запушил на сервер

Tags: git, git-init

Есть рабочий репозиторий с большой историей. Программист случайно выполнил в нем `git init` и отправил на сервер. В итоге была дозаписана куча мусора, права на файлы сменились + еще всякое. Коммит `init` нельзя просто так отменить(`revert`).
Как все таки его отменить и вернуть все назад?

Comment: checkout другой ревисии, потом его init и опять все перезапишет

Comment: [`git init` в уже существующем репозитории ничего не меняет.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428154/181472). Может, какая-то другая команда была использована?

Answer (score 4):

> Внимание! Описаны весьма опасные команды, потенциально деструктивные.
>   Рекомендуется следовать им с осторожностью. Не забудьте сделать
>   резервную копию на всякий случай.

1. Прочитать записи в рефлоге. `git reflog`
2. Сделать `git reset --hard HEAD@{N}` где N - нужный коммит
3. Проверить, что текущая точка именно та, которая нужно.
4. Если состояние устраивает -- то сделать `git push -f` (раз уж вы успели на сервер отправить)

Comment: Для страховки можно оставить на текущем конечном коммите **бэкап-ветку**. И сделать это лучше после того, как сделан `pull`, и предупредив всех коллег, чтобы ничего в репозиторий не закидывали.

Comment: `git init` в уже инициированном репозитории вообще ничего не должен делать. Объясните, пожалуйста, что там у автора произошло?